# what is ([ngModel]) in angular? Is it reverse version of [(ngModel)]?

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms, ngmodel, two-way-binding

I konw what is two way data binding, but there is also ([ngModel]), It is reverse version of [(ngModel)]? then what is ([ngModel])? how it works?

Comment: I don't think there is anything such as `([ngModel])`. We have `[(ngModel)]` for two-way binding but not the first one. If you have came across one and important if that is not throwing errors, can you share link to that, I would be curious to study on that furthur!

Comment: Yes I have came across to that scenario. It is used as ([ngModel])
<select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" ([ngModel])="responseSelected"><option *ngFor="let res of GQR"  [selected]="res.IsDefaultResponse==true" [value]="res.ResponseId">{{res.Response}}</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

`([])` called a **BANANA IN A BOX**.
We can say it's a sugre syntax for two parts:
[ngModel] : to keep the view updated when the model is changing.
(ngModelChange) : to keep model updated when the view is changing.

you can create your own two way binding :  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uc4j2j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: [] = box
() = banana.
[()] = banana in a box
Author asked for ([]) -> Please notice the difference, confusing yes, but a major difference!!